# Getting just a tuple value without a comma

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am reading a table from MySQL using Python as below:

```
input1 = input("Enter the word for meaning: ")
cursor1 = conn.cursor()
count=len(input1)-1
defnres = cursor1.execute("select expression from Dictionary where expression like '{}%'" .format(input1[0:count]))
defnres = cursor1.fetchall()
print(defnres)
```

When I run the code, I enter the following string:

```
rainn
```

I get the following output:

```
[('rain',), ('rain',), ('rain forest',), ('rainout',), ('rain water',), ('rainy',), ('rainbow',), ('raindrop',), ('rain cats and dogs',), ('rain dogs and cats',), ('rain gauge',), ('rain-barrel',), ('rainwater',), ('rainforest',), ('raincoat',), ('rainboots',), ('rainbow boa',), ('rain season',)]
```

I want the output without a comma as below:

```
[('rain'), ('rain'), ('rain forest'), ('rainout'), ('rain water'), ('rainy'), ('rainbow'), ('raindrop',), ('rain cats and dogs'), ('rain dogs and cats'), ('rain gauge'), ('rain-barrel'), ('rainwater'), ('rainforest'), ('raincoat'), ('rainboots'), ('rainbow boa'), ('rain season')]
```

Let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: That output doesn't really make sense; without the comma, they're *not* tuples. Do you want a list of *strings*, `['rain', 'rain', 'rain forest', ...]`?

Comment: ','.join([str(x).replace(',)',')') for x in defnres]) , please try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, as you want to print the list of string you can use:

```
  y = [('rain',), ('rain',), ('rain forest',), ('rainout',)]
  print([x[0] for x in y])
```

output become
['rain', 'rain', 'rain forest', 'rainout']

Answer (score -1):

The essential element here is the trailing comma, that defines the tuple.

```
(1,)
```

[Source](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax)

Example:

```
x = (1)  # int without a comma

x += (2,3)

print(x) # TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

but with:

```
x = (1,)  # tuple

x += (2,3)

print(x)   # (1,2,3)
```

EDIT:

In your case, if you'd want a list of `str`:

```
s = [('rain',), ('rain',), ('rain forest',), ('rainout',)]\

print([x[0] for x in s]) # ['rain', 'rain', 'rain forest', 'rainout']
```

OR

```
print(tuple(x[0] for x in s)) # ('rain', 'rain', 'rain forest', 'rainout')
```